# history replace issue in React Js Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-functional-component

I have three components. for example aComponent bComponent cComponent. aComponent is the parent component It has 100 pages. for example, if I navigate from aComponent to bComponent while coming back it's going to the same page [ex: page no 10]. Whereas if I navigate from aComponent to bComponent and from bComponent to cComponent. while navigating back it's from cComponent -> bComponent -> aComponent it's not going to the exact page.

Note: Here I am calling  bComponent  from aComponent calling like child component
whereas for cComponent from bComponent calling via Links due to my limitations.

```
bComponent.js navigating to cComponent

<Link
to={{
    pathname: '/cComponent/cComponent',
    state: {
        data,
    },
}}
>
<div>Edit </div>
</Link>

 bComponent.js. back action

 const onBack = () => {
        if (location.state) {
            history.replace({
                pathname: './',
                state: location.state,
            });
        } else {
            history.goBack();
        }
    };

cComponent.js back action 

   const goback = () => {
        if (location.state) {
            history.replace({
                pathname: './',
                state: location.state,
            });
        } else {
            history.goBack();
        }
    };
```

I have noticed one thing but am unable to fix the issue that is when I come from cComponent while going back from bComponent to aComponent in debug I notice state is missing in history. if I directly navigate from bComponent to aComponent I am not having any issues.